# Terminal color codes not working as expected

Tags: macos, command-line, mac, unix, prompt

I am using the following code in my `~/.bash_profile` following some online blogs.

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
export TERM="xterm-color"
export PS1='\[\033[1;32m\]$(whoami)@$(hostname): \[\033[0;37m\]$(pwd)$ \[\033[0m\]'
```

The expected output would have been a colored format like `user@host: ~/home/work/dept`. But I am getting output like below:

`\[\033[1;32m\]$(whoami)@$(hostname): \[\033[0;37m\]$(pwd)$ \[\033[0m\]`

I have tried various `~/.bash_profile` codes from various sites but none of them seem to work. This code used to work in my previous Macbook but recently I bought a new Mac and it doesn't seem to work in my new laptop. I tried searching similar question on stackoverflow but couldn't find. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: What shell are you using? Mojave was the last using the BASH shell. Catalina and Big Sur use ZSH. If it is a **new** Mac it runs Catalina and probably the ZSH shell

Comment: Thanks, @SteveChambers your comment helped me. I did not know the default shell in new Macs is zsh. I was assuming it is bash as it used to be in my old Mac. Thanks again.